# QML How to put text cursor at the end of TextEdit element

Tags: qt, qt4, qml, qt-quick

I have a QML `TextEdit` element, I plan for append some text and put the cursor at the end. My method:

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    color: "black"
    anchors.fill: parent
    focus: false

    TextEdit {
        id: txtCommands

        color: "lightGreen"
        anchors.fill: parent
        textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
        wrapMode: TextEdit.WordWrap

        font.family: "Consolas"
        font.pixelSize: 15
        focus: true

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            focus: false
        }

        Keys.onPressed: {
            console.log(event.text)

            switch (event.key) {
            case 16777234: // LEFT
            case 16777235: // UP
            case 16777237: // DOWN
            case 16777236: // RIGHT
                event.accepted = true
                break;

            case 16777220:  // Enter
                txtCommands.text = txtCommands.text + ">: "
                txtCommands.selectAll()
                txtCommands.cursorPosition = txtCommands.text.length
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. How can i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Set `textFormat` to `TextEdit.PlainText` because you have lots of invisible html code otherwise.
2. The following code works for me.

   ```
   Keys.onReturnPressed: {
       event.accepted = true
       txtCommands.text = txtCommands.text + ">: "
       txtCommands.cursorPosition = txtCommands.text.length
   }
   ```

Comment: I set texFormat to TextEdit.plainText then it work fine but I can't set color for some words :-(

Answer (score 3):

If your TextEdit is not in plain text mode `textFormat: TextEdit.PlainText`, and is instead set to `textFormat: TextEdit.RichText`, then
 `txtCommands.text.length` will include the length off all the non-visible html/rtf formatting markup stuff.

The simplest solution is to use `txtCommands.length`.  This property only gives the length of the visible characters.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a string `temp` variable.
2. `temp= TextEdit.getText(0, TextEdit.length)`
3. `TextEdit.cursuorPosition += temp.length`

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you to improve your example by reading the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is the correct answer in my opinion because it preserves the the rich text format property as stated in the question.